# Confusion regarding surface intergrals

Tags: calculus

Why is that if you take the surface integrals of let's say a cylinder parameterized by $x = \cos(\theta)$, $y = \sin(\theta)$, and $z = z$ from $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$ and $ z \in [0,1]$, one does not have to "extrapolate" an equation for the definite integral, of course by letting $\theta = u$ and $z = v$. However, in some problems where the surface integral is calculated and one has an integral of the form $\iint dx\,dy$ you have to bound the integrals by extrapolating an equation such that $y_2(x)$ and $y_1(x)$. Why is this? Thank you.

Comment: Letting $\theta=u$ and $z=v$ is merely re-naming variables.

Comment: This is one of the more unclearly expressed questions I've seen. "Extrapolate" usually means extending something beyond its known bounds, and "such that $y_2(x)$ and $y_1(x)$ omits the verb, so its impossible to know what is meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, when you change coordinates from $(x,y,z)$ to $(r, \theta,z)$ you're doing the same thing. However, the 'surface' or 'volume' of the cylinder is 'special' enough that you can just set $r= \rho$ and $\theta \in [0, 2\pi)$ and be done with it, but if you were to use $(x,y,z)$ coords to evaluate the same integral you would have to integrate first with either x or y and figure out the bounds of that one in terms of the other, $y_1 = -\sqrt{\rho^2-x^2}$, $y_2 = \sqrt{\rho^2-x^2}$. This is actually the reason that we use different (cylindrical, polar, hyperbolic, etc) coordinate systems to tackle integrals because some coordinate changes make them easier to evaluate.

Parametrizing out space differently may allow us to simplify our expressions!